# Rules working in VirtualHost but not in .htaccess

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I am using Apache 2.4. I am facing a strange problem. I have some rewrite rules defined in my virtualhosts and it's working fine. But if I even put "RewriteEngine on" in my .htaccess file, the rewrite rules defined in the virtualhost no longer works.

I tried removing the rules from the virtual hosts and pasting it into the .htaccess but it doesn't work. For some reason it only works in the virutalhosts.

What am I doing wrong?

Following are my virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/sites/test.com/public_html

    <Directory />
            Require all granted
            AllowOverride All

            # Redirect http to https
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(blog) [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/sites/test.com/public_html

    SSLEngine ...

    <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

            # Rewrite .html to .php
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(blog) [NC]
            RewriteCond "$1.php" -f
            RewriteCond "$1.html" !-f
            RewriteRule "^(.*).html$" "$1.php"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you may get a loop with /404.html. Consider using the NS,L flags in the rule.

Comment: I commented that line but it's still the same problem.

Comment: it's inheritance issue. I reproduced the above with `RewriteOptions Inherit` in htaccess. Try also `RewriteOptions InheritDown` inside the `<Directory />`

Comment: @Deadooshka Still no luck. Why doesn't it work if I completely remove rewrite rules from the `<Directory />` and only apply it in .htaccess? The .htaccess is in the root directory.

Comment: I got a bug with path-prefix in `<Directory />`. In order to avoid this bug specify a complete docroot filesystem path `<Directory /path/to/root>`

Comment: If I add the path to root .html links no longer works.

Comment: this is because the `$1` in Conds isn't contain a full filesystem path and thus requres a prefix `/home/test/sites/test.com/public_html/$1`. With `<Directory />` it does contain a full path, but it's a wrong behavior for `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Deadooshka. Please convert your inheritance comment to an answer please.